# Viewing file from Git using JGIT remotely without creating local repo

Tags: jgit

I m writing a web application where it accepts the git URL and file to read and then displays the file on the webpage. I m using JGit for this. I see that JGit needs a local repository to clone before viewing the file. Since this is server, I do not have access to local files. So, is there anyway I can access the git remotely and view the file from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not just JGit that needs a local repository, Git itself requires a local repository.  Centralized version control systems like CVS and SVN had remote server viewing built-in, but decentralized systems (such as Git and Mercurial) typically do not.

If you want to browse a Git server, you have to make a local clone, but you could do this in the background for the user.

You might also be interested in the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/), which lets you do what you want, but only for repositories hosted by GitHub.

Comment: Hi Ned...Is it still the same case i.e. we can't do any remote server viewing using JGIT?

Comment: It's not because of JGIT, it's because of Git.  Git can't do it.  GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket - they all have proprietary APIs that can do it.  But not Git.

Comment: Ned, for Bitbucket what API can I use?  My GIT is on Bitbucket. I want to remotely read the data without cloning the repo.